# Eclipse/Android: "Choose Project" missing selections?

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I'm using Eclipse Indigo (fully patched) on Mac OS X 10.7.4 (fully patched). The ADT is installed and everything is up to date through the Android SDK Manager. Java is provided by Apple and is 1.6.0.33.

I'm trying to create a new "Android Activity." When prompted, I cannot select a project. There are no selections in the drop down.

Eclipse is installed in /Applications, and has the ADT installed. The Android SDK and NDK are installed in /opt/local/android-sdk and /opt/local/android-ndk. Eclipse's preferences show the paths correctly and the installed APIs (2.2 - 4.1).

The problem exists when launching through the Eclipse icon (alias) from my login; and when running from the command line as root: `sudo /Applications/.Eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be going on or how to fix it?

[image: Missing Project Selections].

Comment: Do you have any Android projects in your workspace? You chose the "Android Activity" wizard, not the "Android Application Project" wizard.

Comment: "Android Activity" - thanks CommonWare. I clarified that's what I selected.

Comment: You did not answer my question. Do you have any Android projects in your workspace? You cannot define an activity without a project.

Comment: My bad - Doh. I'd like to delete this question.... If you provide the answer, I will provide the points.

Comment: The right answer is already here (swayam's).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a Project to define an Activity.

So, either you import an already existing Project into your workspace and then create the new Activity or select the "Android Application Project" wizard to create a new project and add the new Activity to it.